# On Android is it possible to detect if a user bought your app before it became free?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

We've got an app on the marketplace. It was 0.99c paid, and the user could use it as much as they want. We decided to update the app to run from in app purchases instead, and give the app away for free.

I tried to detect which installs were fresh installs and which were updates by detecting if a previous install had left persisted data behind. This way we could give the older (paid) customers a tweaked app so they got what they paid for.

This failed for an unknown reason so **now we're in the sticky situation where all the *paid* customers think they've been ripped off and now only have a limited app.** We want to fix this, but we're worried there's no longer a way to discern between paid and free downloads.

If there was a way to tell *when* they bought the app - that would be enough.

We even considered updating the app with a way for customers to type in their email addresses, so we could check if that user was one of the old paid customers. But apparently Google have taken away the ability to see their email addresses recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by releasing a second free app where you needed in app purchases to use, Then released an update to the old app that put it back to how it was so the annoyed customers were happy. We then unpublished the old app - so that only those that had already downloaded it could use it. All this works out as we're now left with happy paid customers, and new customers get the free app with in app purchases.

Comment: @beworker it's slightly different. My new free application doesn't detect if the older app is installed, and the old app doesn't tell you to transition. The old application is now free and unlimited - but unpublished so new downloads are not allowed. The new application requires in app purchases for all users.

Answer (score 1):

I have same need too and here is how I think I could solve the puzzle. Just an idea.

I'm going to release a new app (with new package name) which will be free and will have an in-app billing function. This app will enable paid functions when either (a) a user bought in-app product or (b) a user has my old paid app installed. The paid app functionality will be replaced with a single activity asking user to migrate to new free app. It will also ask user to keep old app installed as an activation key for the new one. In turn old app will be removed form the market. I think Google Play works in the way, that all users who bought an app before it was removed, will still be able to see and install it afterwards.

Comment: This seems promising. So we effectively make a new free app and within it we detect if the old app is installed. If it is, then we give them the feature. Otherwise they have to buy in apps. Seems plausible.